# Not able to pass form contents to view model in actionresult

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass a string (which represents the button that has been clicked) and the contents of a form, but when the code reaches the actionresult, the vModel object is always null.  Could anyone help me to fix it?

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
    var form = $('#Application');
    if (form.valid()) {
            var data = { 
                'submitButton': "Submit your application",
                'vModel': JSON.stringify(form.serialize())
            };

            $("#submit-application-dialog").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: "auto",
                width: 400,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Submit application": function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: form.attr('action'),
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: data,
                            success: $("#submit-application-dialog").dialog("close")
                        });
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
     }
```

And the actionresult:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Application(string submitButton, ApplicationViewModel vModel)
    {
    ...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a similar thing by appending the value to the query string like the below instead of having a controller action parameter.

```
var myData = $('#frmMyForm').serialize();
myData = myData + "&ButtonClicked=" + "Button1";             

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("MyActionName", "MyControllerName")",
                data: myData,
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                success: function(data) {
                \\Do stuff here if needed;
                }
```

Then in the controller I pull the value from the forms collection.

```
var buttonName = Request.Form["ButtonClicked"];
```

There may well be a better or shall we say less clunky way of doing this but this worked for me.

Hope that helps

Hello, there is actually a better solution which I thought of last night. Add a property to your view model perhaps called "ButtonClicked".

Then in JQuery, catch the click event of the submit like below and set the button name accordingly.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).on("click", "#btnSubmitButton", function () {
            $("#ButtonClicked").val("ThisButton");
        });

    });
 </script>
```

This is then bound to the posted model.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this, it has really helped me with the solution.  So i've kept the original two properties in the ActionResult, but used your 'var myData...' code and it is now passing everything through correctly :).

Comment: @Diz19791 - Hi.. there was a better solution i think.. i've edited the answer. ta